# Image displaying in different places depening on browser

Tags: html, css, position

I'm building a very simple site using HTML and CSS. It consists of a headline, a paragraph of text, and an image.

When I view the site on Chrome, the placement of all three objects works perfectly. But in Firefox and Safari, they're scrambled. When I then optimize for one of those two, the Chrome version looks off. Etc.

Here's the CSS:

```
img {
position: fixed;
bottom: 280px;
right: 800px;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
 <img src="bob.jpg" height="50%" width="20%">
```

Is there a relatively simple way to fix this? Can I specify the positioning depending on the browser -- something like so?

```
 img {
position: fixed;
/* Chrome
bottom: 350px;
right: 925px;
 /* Firefox
 bottom: 200px;
right: 800px;
}
```

etc.

And a second question: What property can I assign the image so that text always wraps around the image, rather than rendering in front of or behind it?

Thank you!

Comment: Please explain the need for `fixed` position.

Comment: @Aziz No reason. What would you suggest I use instead?

Comment: Could you please share a basic sketch of how the layout should look like? Using `fixed` is usually for elements who are supposed to stay in one location in the viewport (sticky)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the image to be centered and aligned with the page's content, there is no need to add any additional CSS since you have `text-align: center` added to the `body`.

The image will be centered since it is an inline element. Also, your code has many issues, consider a simplified version:

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

hr {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 3em auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <h3>THE X-FILES EPISODE GENERATOR</h3>
  <hr>
  <p>Make your own episode!</p>
  <p>The X-Files generator mixes people, places and plots from different episodes to create new adventures.</p>
  <hr>
  <div class="wrap">
    <button onclick="sentenceLoad()">Generate</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h5></h5>
  </div>
  <img src="https://bobbyfestgenerator.github.io/X.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

- Use CSS margin instead of repetitive `<br>` tags
- No need to redefine the font since it is inherited from `body`
- Add CSS rules to external file instead of inline (for `<hr>` for example)
- Use `margin: 0 auto` to center block-level elements like `<p>`

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/d1xmv65m/